# How to send Facebook notifications using API - to all friends of a user?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, notifications, facebook-friends

I have been looking for a solution to this from last few weeks now.

As per Facebook docs, https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/permissions#reference-user_friends

> In order for a person to show up in one person's friend list, both
>   people must have decided to share their list of friends with your app
>   and not disabled that permission during login. Also both friends must
>   have been asked for user_friends during the login process.

...And notification API needs friends' ID:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/games/services/appnotifications#implementation

As per this information, one cannot send notifications to all friends (or to be precise, cannot send notification to a user who has not authorized your app for the same).

...but I get notifications from apps I haven't authorized (I checked, revoked permissions; still get notifications). What am I missing here?

Example of one such app: Candy Crush (Game).

Comment: There is no way to do that.

Comment: @WizKid exactly. I believe you. I believe the docs. BUT I'm getting notifications from apps I have actually unauthorized. Just need an explanation for that.

Comment: How to invite people to your app is explained here https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/faq#faq_104376946653191